# Use break into closures [Swift]

Tags: swift, break

In my swift app I've the following function:

```
func getImages() {

    var i = 0
    K: while (true) {
        let downloadURL = URL(string: "serverURL")
        Database.downloadImage(withURL: downloadURL!) { (image) in

            if image == nil { break }

            self.imagesArray.append(image!)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to get images from server, but I don't know the exactly number of the images.
But this is the error for if statement that check nil value:

> Unlabeled 'break' is only allowed inside a loop or switch, a labeled break is required to exit an if or do.

How can I solve, Is it necessary to know the number of images to limit the loop?

Comment: Do not use a `while (true)` loop here. It will kick off thousands of downloads before the first one completes.

Comment: What have I to use ?

Comment: As rmaddy says, your code is a train-wreck, and can't possibly work correctly.Do not use that approach. @Sh_Khan's approach would work.

Comment: So you're trying to download the same image `i` times until it eventually fails? I don't understand, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Alexander i don't think this it's the case as it would be meaningless

Comment: @Sh_Khan Well yes, I know, that's why I suspect I'm not understanding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desipte it's very important to know count of images , you can use this

```
func getImages(_ i:Int) {

        let downloadURL = URL(string: "serverURL")
        Database.downloadImage(withURL: downloadURL!) { (image) in

            if let img = image { 

            self.imagesArray.append(img)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            getImages(i+1)

           }
           else {
               print("image is nil final call")
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Also may be the download is dependent on i as not to make an infinite loop

Comment: This downloads them serially, which is also very suboptimal. Side note, don't do `!= nil` ... `!`. Just use conditional binding instead.

Comment: @Alexander every download should depend on **i** and since count of downloads is unknown then it's the straight-forward approach i can't init concurrent requests of unknown results  , and yes if let should be here as i cared to solve main case

Comment: @Sh_Khan This question just needs clearer requirements from OP. Although even still, this could be improved by chunking it into batches of `n` concurrent downloads, and discarding any undesired results after. It'll cause some extraneous downloads, but it'll speed up the total time `n` times.